# How would i go about creating a streaming API, that receives data from a POST request and pushes it out?

Tags: api, sockets, websocket, socket.io, streaming

I am interested in developing an API that is capable of receiving data in real-time and pushing it out to clients connected to an endpoint. I have looked in socket.io and web sockets. However, these depend on events being triggered to send/receive data. This isn't ideal for my use case. What alternatives are there for me to achieve this?

Any help and advice are greatly appreciated.

Comment: welcome to Stack overflow, Please check (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)how to ask a good question. Your question is currently missing too much information to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand it right, you want to write a streaming service that can push updates on some data in real-time over an endpoint exposed to the clients. I guess webhooks might be a solution looking into your problem statement. I'd recommend you to look into this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63grynZmo7c as well. It has got elementary information as to how do you create a webhook and start receiving real-time updates on it

Comment: Thanks for that, ill look into it. Say I just wanted to stream data to a user through an endpoint, would it be possible to just create a http stream and how would I go about that. Most of the examples online relate to video streaming. I want to stream JSON data.

Comment: https://technicalsand.com/streaming-data-spring-boot-restful-web-service/. Maybe you can check this one out :). But I would still recommend you have a webhook server-server communication, if you are thinking about real time seamless streaming

Comment: Yeah i think your right regarding the use of webhooks for my use case. However, most of the implementations examples online are in java spring boot. You think it's possible to achieve the same using node js. If you have any resources that I could potentially, id appreciate it if you could send them over.